# Total capacitance of two sets of parallel capacitors and resistors in series.

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, dc, parallel

Assuming C1 and C2 both are rated at 2.5V.

Is the total capacitance of C1 and C2 0.5uF or 1uF?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7ShuH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The capacitors are not directly in series so normal simple series capacitors formulas do not apply. You have to analyze the circuit as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate series or parallel capacitance of capacitors between Node 2 and ground because they are neither in series nor in parallel. You have to calculate total impedance between Node 2 and ground. Since this is a DC circuit, at steady state, assuming all transients have died, C1 and C2 would be open circuited. No current will flow through them. Current only flows in outer mesh through R3, R1 and R2 resistors.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming you need to calculate the impedance between Node2 and ground. Well, this is not a purely reactance value, i.e. it has real impedance components due to the resistors. Calculate C1//R1 in series with C2//R2 and this is it.

X1 = 1/jwC1
X2 = 1/jwC2

Where j is the imaginary number.

Comment: You probably meant to write X= instead of C=.

Comment: Also, this answer should be showing calculations for Z.

Comment: @Reinderien Sure

Comment: assuming the circuit is purely for DC voltage, what is the benefit of having R1 and R2 instead of just C1 and C2? Does the resistors make sure C2 is fully charged (in case C1 gets charged up first thus blocking current to C2).

Comment: There’s no benefit or disadvantage until you specify an application for that circuit